# POST variable is not being saved correctly

Tags: php, forms

Im using method post to send a mutliple input text form, i draw information from the database to after re insert the information which is inside input text:

```
echo "<CENTER><TABLE BORDER='0'>";
echo "<FORM METHOD='POST'>";
$sele_players = "SELECT nombre FROM JUGADORES WHERE NOM_EQUIPO='Aston villa'";
        $sele_players = mysql_query( $sele_players , $link );

        while( $row = @mysql_fetch_assoc( $sele_players ) )
        {
            $row['nombre'] = addslashes( $row['nombre'] );
            echo "<TR><TD ALIGN='CENTER'>".$row['nombre']."</TD>";
            echo "<TD><INPUT TYPE='TEXT' NAME='{$row['nombre']}'></TD></TR>";
        }

        echo "<TR><TD COLSPAN='2' ALIGN='CENTER'><INPUT TYPE='submit' NAME='send2' VALUE='INSERTAR' style='width:200px; height:60px' ></TD></CENTER></TR>";
```

ok here i get the names of players from database, then i use them for insert inside input text as his name, to after pick with array $_POST:

```
    if( !empty( $_POST['send2'] ) )
    {

        foreach($_POST as $jugador => $points)
        {
            $jugador = str_replace( "__" ,". ", $jugador );
            $jugador = str_replace( "_" ," ", $jugador );

            if( $points == "" )
            {
                $points = "NULL";
            }

            $inser_jornada = "INSERT INTO JORNADA VALUES( '{$_GET['jornada']}','{$_GET['equipo']}', '$jugador', '$points', now() );";
```

So there is no problem with most of names, excluding N'Zogbia name or apostrophe names which is shown in $_POST array as 'N', i have tried adding slashes before send it through from but doesnt work, so i dont know how to get the complete name in post array, thats the main problem.

THanks forwarded!!

Comment: `print_r($_REQUEST);` see if anything is populated.. If not, check the names of your HTML inputs.

Comment: I can't even begin to explain how many elements of bad design are in here.

Comment: I think my favourite is `<center>`, though.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things to point out here. But instead of that, I will try my best to be helpful.

Add your database entries using `mysql_real_escape_string($variableName)` to enter the content to the database. It will automatically escape such quotes and make it a little SQL Injection proof.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned before, your code "screams" help. There are lot of things to point out, but back to your answer: I think your problem is in the following line:

```
 $inser_jornada = "INSERT INTO JORNADA VALUES( '{$_GET['jornada']}','{$_GET['equipo']}', '$jugador', '$points', now() );";
```

Try this instead:

```
$inser_jornada = 'INSERT INTO JORNADA VALUES( "' . $_GET['jornada'] . '", "' . $_GET['equipo'] . '", "' . $jugador . '", "' . $points . '", now() );';
```

I would really, really recommend that you run mysqli_real_escape_string() to all your input.

Good luck!